# How to merge the elements in a list in a simpler way? Prolog

Tags: list, merge, prolog

I am trying to merge the elements in a list, the rules are as follows:

**1.** Merge a list in a way that if 2 consecutive numbers in a list are a same number they should merge into one by summing them (i.e. [4,4,0,0] -> [8,0,0,0]).

**2.** A newly merged tile cannot be combined with another
tile in the same turn (Example: [4,4,8,0] ->[8,8,0,0] True, but [16,0,0,0] False)

**3.** List length should be 4. Which adds a zero to the tail if list decreases after merging. (Example: [4,4,0,2] -> [8,0,2,0]).

**4.** Note in case of zeros: [0,0,2,2] -> [0,4,0,0].

I have been able to create the code, however I want to find a simpler approach explained in detail.

My approach:

```
merge([H|T],L):-
   merge2([H|T],J),
    (
    length(J,2)->  
    append(J,[0,0],L);
    length(J,3)->  
    append(J,[0],L);length(J,4)-> J=L).

merge2(_,[]).
merge2([X],[X|_]).
merge2([H1,H2|T],[W|L]):-
    H1=H2,
    W is H1+H2,
    merge2(T,L).
merge2([H1,H2|T],[H1|L]):-
    H1\=H2,
    merge2([H2|T],L).
```

Comment: where do the new zeros in the tail are coming from? why not [4,4,0,0] --> [8,0] and [4,4,8,0] ->[8,8,0] ?

Comment: The list should be of length 4, so whenever an action happens, 0 is added if the length decreases..

Comment: what about [2,2,2,2]? -> [4,2,2,0] or [4,4,0,0]?

Comment: @Raubsauger it should be [4,4,0,0]

Comment: just to be clear: [4,4,0,2] -> [8,0,2,0] and not [8,2,0,0], [0,0,2,2] -> [0,4,0,0] and not [4,0,0,0]?

Comment: no, 0=0, so it is [0,4,0,0] according to your definition. you didn't say 0s should be skipped over.

Comment: @WillNess I said to add the zeros in the tail.

Comment: yes, {[0,0,2,2]} -> [0+0, ...{[2,2]} ...[0]] -> [0+0, ...[2+2,0], ...[0]] -> [0,4,0,0], where `{....}` means "perform the transformation" and `[ A, ...[B] ]` is list-splicing pseudocode standing, in this case, for `[A|B]`.

Comment: @Raubsauger Sorry, It should be [0,4,0,0] I stay corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for arbitrary-length lists and in a single pass without `append`. (But as a rare occasion for me, with a cut!)

The main predicate dispatches to a helper that counts the number of zeros to add at the end:

```
merge(List, Merged) :-
    merge(List, 0, Merged).
```

The important clause of the helper merges two adjacent equal values. It also increments the counter of zeros to be added at the end:

```
merge([X, X | Xs], ExtraZeros, [Sum | MergedRest]) :-
    !,
    Sum is X + X,
    merge(Xs, s(ExtraZeros), MergedRest).
```

Otherwise, copy elements until we reach the end of the list:

```
merge([X | Xs], ExtraZeros, [X | Ys]) :-
    merge(Xs, ExtraZeros, Ys).
```

At the end of the list, generate zeros as needed:

```
merge([], ExtraZeros, ZeroList) :-
    length_zerolist(ExtraZeros, ZeroList).

length_zerolist(0, []).
length_zerolist(s(N), [0 | Zeros]) :-
    length_zerolist(N, Zeros).
```

Tests from the question:

```
?- merge([4, 4, 0, 0], Merged).
Merged = [8, 0, 0, 0].

?- merge([4, 4, 8, 0], Merged).
Merged = [8, 8, 0, 0].

?- merge([4, 4, 0, 2], Merged).
Merged = [8, 0, 2, 0].

?- merge([0, 0, 2, 2], Merged).
Merged = [0, 4, 0, 0].
```

A longer list:

```
?- merge([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5], Merged).
Merged = [0, 2, 2, 6, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0].
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Can you explain to me what is this: s(N) and s(ExtraZeros). I have never seen this before in prolog. :)

Comment: @ReemaQKhan when `merge/3` starts working, its 2nd argument is `0`. then in the case of summation, `0` is turned into `s(0)`, or it stays `0` if there was no summation. then `s(0)` is turned into `s(s(0))` and so forth, and in general `ExtraZeros` is turned into `s(ExtraZeros)` in case the summation was performed, or stays the same if it wasn't. if we count the number of the nested `s`'s in that compound term we'll see that its depth is the same as the number of the summations that we have done. this is known as Peano arithmetics, or counting in unary (as opposed to binary, or decimal).

Comment: this is much better than my ad hoc answer. :) simple and clear, too.

Answer (score 4):

Length 4 is not long enough to not just write out the cases:

```
merge( [A,B,C,D], Y) :-
  ( A=B -> ( C=D -> X=[A+B,C+D,0,0] 
                 ;  X=[A+B,C,D,0] )
        ;  ( B=C -> X=[A,B+C,D,0]
                 ;  ( C=D -> X=[A,B,C+D,0]
                          ;  X=[A,B,C,D] ))),
  maplist(is,Y,X).
```

This just writes out the cases according to your specification. We spare ourselves having to manually call `is` each time we add two variables by instead writing the sums down symbolically, with `+`, and call `is` for each element of the result at once in the end, via `maplist`.

Comment: Could you maybe explain your code, especially the maplist part.

Comment: you're welcome. :) it would've been harder if the length wasn't known, perhaps.